# sort multidimensional array in php by key of inner array

Tags: php, api, sorting, multidimensional-array, ksort

I want to sort the Job titles by timestamp "1357894278"

```
<?php
foreach( $jobs as &$job )
{
    $cj_date[] =  array( strtotime($job->date) => array( $job->title ));
}

foreach ($results['results'] as $result)
{
    $in_date[] = array ( strtotime($result['date']) => array ($result['jobtitle']) );
}

$ans[] = array_merge($cj_date,$in_date);

foreach($ans as $a)  
{
    ksort($a);
    print_r($a);
}
?>
```

By running this this script I got my output as following:

```
Array( [0] => Array
              ( [1352796106] => Array 
                                ( [0] => JobTitle_1 )
              )
       [1] => Array
              ( [1352745201] => Array 
                                ( [0] => JobTitle_2 )
              )
       [2] => Array
              ( [1357894278] => Array 
                                ( [0] => JobTitle_3 )
              )
      )
```

So How to sort the Job-Titles by 1352796106, 1352745201, 1357894278
Thanks!
Wait for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function compare($a, $b) {
    $ak = array_keys($a);
    $bk = array_keys($b);
    return ($ak[0] < $bk[0]) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($ans, "compare");
var_dump($ans);
```

[`usort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) sorts by a custom comparison function.

Comment: in the output it first shows all the results regarding the first API and the Another API.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem a while back. I had a much more complex structure. I ended up creating another array as my 'map', and I used it for sorting/indexing.

The new map array was a very simple structure that only contained necessary information about my other structure, just enough information to index quickly and to sort quickly as well.

I am sure there may be other solutions, but this worked for me because I had very large complex structures that will be more expensive to iterate throught if I did not have that extra map structure. It all comes down to you calcuating your time-cost and finding out if it is going to be expensive or not for you depending on the complexity and the size of your data types.

Comment: can you give me example of your map array.
because I'm working on the results that came through the APIs so I can't able to sort it by any index name like $ans['date'].

Comment: What in your situation, what I did would be something similar to this:  `Array([jobTitle1]=>0, [jobtitle2]=>1)`. So basically it is an indexing array stating that jobtite1 is actually item 0 in theoriginal array.

Comment: Wahab Mirjan thx for the help. 
But now I got a solution. I just make a mistake in the array merge.